# Can you play friends in ranked matches on Soul Calibur V for PS3?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

Wondering if so. If you can then I might want to get Soul Calibur V. That is the one thing lacking in Soul Calibur IV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Ranked matches are *always* random, across every game you could ever play. If they weren't, it would be terribly easy to rig them and boost your ranked score for free.

If you want to play with your friend, you will have to choose some more casual mode.

Comment: that sucks. i feel like a waste of time to play with nothing to show for it like rankings. thanks for your answer